# How to fix page shrinkage?

Tags: html, css

Page minimization problem @media I can't use.

I tried universal selector, body selector and container selector. When the page drops below 1200px, the container should shrink, but it doesn't. These are my codes;

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #e8e6e3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    width: 1172px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: please include your full code

Answer (score 0):

The container doesn't shrink down along with the page because you've hardcoded it to always remain 1172px wide.
Thus it'll never get any bigger or smaller than that, regardless of your viewport size.

---

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use `@media` queries here, but you could use a relative unit of measurement like `vw` (which will make it size along with the viewport width) or `%` (which will make it size along with the parent element) instead.

Comment: When I use vw and %, the container layout on the page is broken. 1172 is the page itself, when I break it everything breaks.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your code exactly is, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Could you share your HTML as well so we can take a look at that? Without that, I'd just have to **assume** the `.container` is a seperate DIV you can style as you wish.

Also, why can't you use `@media` queries here?